# App store for the PC?

Tags: publishing, software-distribution

So I've spent a lot of time making an iPhone game and have recently realized that I don't have to limit myself to just Apple - I know there are app stores for Palm and Android, but does anybody know of a good "app store" for the plain old PC? I would like to have one where individual developers can publish an app and not have to worry about all the billing and piracy issues!

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion, but if you think iPhone developers don't have to "worry about piracy issues", you'd be surprised... :)

Comment: I know first hand that the iPhone has piracy issues! I still think Apple's solution is better than something I could hack together in my spare time though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valve has Steam, although that's a bit of a game store. It comes with DRM so it might be what you want. http://store.steampowered.com/

From what I can see, their website has an email to coontact them about distribution and that's it. steamworks@valvesoftware.com

Stardock has Impulse, which is more of a general app store although it does have games as well. No DRM baked in, and it has a very liberal return policy. http://www.impulsedriven.com/

Impulse has a page with more info and a contact form - https://developer.impulsedriven.com/#publishing
The page states the base rate is 70% which is likely more than Steam gives you.